# Typo3: How to get the View exception error

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

I am Developing a custom extension for Typo3. now I am getting an error if the user did not include my extension from template's include section.

I want to catch this error to show a message from controller. How can I do this?

my controller action.

```
 public function listAction()
 {
    $audits = $this->auditRepository->findAll();
    $this->view->assign('arrDetails', $audits);
 }
```

Comment: Do you mean that if someone has forgotten to add the STATIC template, you would like to show a message which tells the user that he forgot to add it?

Comment: Exactly!. some users are not aware of this. so users think that it is an error from my extension. so if I could I can solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be one solution, but not the cleanest.

We first need to get the values from the field `include_static_file` that it is located on the sys_template table. So:

```
$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getConnectionForTable('sys_template')->createQueryBuilder();
$result = $queryBuilder
       ->select('include_static_file')
       ->from('sys_template')
       ->execute()
       ->fetch(0);
```

The we need to get the string and evaluate if your extension key is present. So:

```
 $extKey = 'your_extension_key';

 if (strpos($result['include_static_file'], $extKey) !== false) {
    $audits = $this->auditRepository->findAll();
    $this->view->assign('arrDetails', $audits);
 }
 else {
    $this->addFlashMessage(
            'You forgot to add the static template',
            $messageTitle = 'Template is missing',
            $severity = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\AbstractMessage::WARNING,
            $storeInSession = TRUE
        );
 }
```

Your **HTML**

```
<f:if condition="{arrDetails}">
    <f:then>
        do something with your content
    </:then>
    <f:else>
           <f:flashMessages />
    </f:else>
</f:if>
```

Of course you can write a static function for this or you can use the `LocalizationUtility` in order to get the text in multiple languages. It is up to you.

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need your static template?

I think it is important that some values you fetch from typoscript got meaningful content.
As you inspect them anyway you can output a message if one or more values are empty.

Your plugin would work in an installation if all necessary values are set in any way. Even if your static template is not included.
And your plugin would fail if your static template is included but following typoscript would erase the settings from it.

In your error message you can note the possibility to use the values from your static template.